# Obtain request inside ShouldSerialize predicate of Json Custom ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, c#-5.0

I need to obtain the current request context querystring inside the predicate of a property.ShouldSerialize function. I am using .net 5.0.

I am currently injecting HttpContext as such:

`public MyContractResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)`

And attempting to access it as such:

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
   var request = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

   property.ShouldSerialize = p =>
      {
         query = request.(get stuff I need)
      }
}
```

I am registering the resolver in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

   services.AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
   {
      IServiceProvider container = services.BuildServiceProvider();
      var httpContextAccessor = container.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

      opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ContractResolver(httpContextAccessor);
   }
}
```

This works fine for the first request, however subsequent requests fail with the error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
```

This actually makes sense as the original HttpContext that was created in startup has been disposed (I believe at Startup they are only scoped to that function)

However, I need to check the request information on future requests as the query string may have changed. The only way to get it to work so far is to CreateContract on every request, which is not ideal as it has a lot of overhead.

Comment: Where does `httpContextAccessor`, the argument passed to the constructor, come from?

Comment: services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); registers the HttpContextAccessor as a singleton during startup and is therefore available via dependency injection.

Comment: Yes but that's not my question. I was asking where `httpContextAccessor` comes from in the registration code `services.AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
   {
      opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ContractResolver(httpContextAccessor);
   }`

Comment: Good question. I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have solved this by not using Dependency Injection at all but instead instantiating the HttpContextAccessor independently, as below:

```
property.ShouldSerialize = p =>
{
   var request = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext?.Request;

   ...
}
```